# How do I programmatically update the rendering language?

Tags: 8, views

I am trying to programmatically set the Views rendering language of a couple of Views having multiple displays. I found that doing it manually is error prone.

```php
use Drupal\views\Views;

$view = Views::getView('ap_country');
print_r($view->display_id);

$view->setHandlerOption('page_2', 'argument', 'nid', 'admin_label', 'Foo');
$view->save();
```

I am trying to achieve something like the above and then export the View. However rendering language does not seem to be a handler.

The reason behind dong this is currently all the views are set to the current Interface language and I want to switch to the content language.

Comment: Export, edit the YML file in a text-editor, search and replace the config key you want to change, re-import.

Comment: Why don't you do this with configuration management? Like get a local copy of the site. Export all config. Then update either the Views and export config again or update the config manually; and push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is not a handler setting. This is configured directly in a display.

To update a View programmatically use the storage property of the View object (which is by the way a reference to the config object discussed in the comments) and get a reference of a display (the master display is `default`):

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('myview');
$storage = $view->storage;
$display = &$storage->getDisplay('page_2');
$display['display_options']['rendering_language'] = '***LANGUAGE_language_content***';
$storage->save();
```